# Как полученные данные из облака отобразить на spinner

Tags: android, java

как полученные данные из облако,  отобразить на spinner. изменяю вот этот пример [link text][1] в этом примере данные отображают в  ListView. Мне надо через Spinnet.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables
    ListView listview;
    List<ParseObject> ob;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    private List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
        // Execute RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
        new RemoteDataTask().execute();
    }

    // RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
    private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Parse.com Custom ListView Tutorial");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create the array
            worldpopulationlist = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
            try {
                // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                        "Country");
                // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
                // by ascending
                query.orderByAscending("ranknum");
                ob = query.find();
                for (ParseObject country : ob) {
                    // Locate images in flag column
                    ParseFile image = (ParseFile) country.get("flag");

                    WorldPopulation map = new WorldPopulation();
                    map.setRank((String) country.get("rank"));
                    map.setCountry((String) country.get("country"));
                    map.setPopulation((String) country.get("population"));
                    map.setFlag(image.getUrl());
                    worldpopulationlist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                    worldpopulationlist);
            // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}

  [1]: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/

Вот я нашел пример с Spinner. но как указать массив, полученный из сети

final String[] daynames = getResources().getStringArray(
        R.array.dayofweek); // массив строк мы определили в ресурсах ранее

Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

SpinnerAdapter spinneradapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, daynames);
((ArrayAdapter<String>) spinneradapter).setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner.setAdapter(spinneradapter);
```

Comment: @Ильмир Сулейманов, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
ArrayAdapter<WorldPopulation> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<WorldPopulation>(this, R.layout.item, R.id.text, worldpopulationlist); 
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.drop_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

В классе WorldPopulation нужно переопределить метод toString(), то что будет возвращать этот метод, тот текст и будет в соответствующем пункте спинера.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        aArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        aArrayAdapter

                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        try {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                    "Group");
            query.orderByAscending("group");
            ob = query.find();

            for (ParseObject country : ob) {
                aArrayAdapter.add((String) country.get("group"));
            }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("my", "error = " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        spinner.setAdapter(aArrayAdapter);

    }
}
```

}